# Having a vector as input for limit in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, input, vector, limit

**I have this question:
Show that lim e^x-1/x where x->0 by defining a vector x with elements 1 0.5 0.1 0.001 0.00001 0.0000001 and using element-by-element operations.**

At first i did :

x=[1 0.5 0.1 0.0001 0.00001 0.0000001];

F= (exp(x)-1)/x;

limitFunction=limit(F)

frpintf('Limit is equal to: %6.2f',limitFunction);

---

but it says that it doesn't like double as input so i did : syms x with some other adjustments at print and it was okk ...BUT this is not solving the question :/

Answer (score 1):

```
syms x
F= (exp(x)-1)/x;
limit(F,x,0)
```

or

```
x=[1 0.5 0.1 0.0001 0.00001 0.0000001];
F= (exp(x)-1)./x;
```

you need to use `./` for element-wise division.

Comment: Yeah.. that's true.. but still i cannot find a way to use as input my vector in the limit .. it doesn't like it ...